# How can I add css and js to php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am using simple script to save and retrieve photo and description and it works fine, but I need to apply script "jquery.magnific-popup.js" to the photos and I added the function and I added the class to the echo statement but am not sure if is that true or not.

Here is the php file :

```
<?php
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',300);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);
?>
<html>
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">

</header>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <br/>
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
            {
                if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
                {
                    echo "Please select an image.";
                }
                else
                {
                    $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                    $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                    $image= file_get_contents($image);
                    $image= base64_encode($image);
                    saveimage($name,$image);
                }
            }
            displayimage();
            function saveimage($name,$image)
            {
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("kstark",$con);
                $qry="insert into images (name,image) values ('$name','$image')";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                if($result)
                {
                    //echo "<br/>Image uploaded.";
                }
                else
                {
                    //echo "<br/>Image not uploaded.";
                }
            }
            function displayimage()
            {
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("kstark",$con);
                $qry="select * from images";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                    echo '<img class="image-link" height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
                }
                mysql_close($con);   
            }
        ?>

         <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $('.image-link').magnificPopup({ 
  type: 'image',
  mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom', // this class is for CSS animation below

  zoom: {
    enabled: true, // By default it's false, so don't forget to enable it

    duration: 300, // duration of the effect, in milliseconds
    easing: 'ease-in-out', // CSS transition easing function 

    // The "opener" function should return the element from which popup will be zoomed in
    // and to which popup will be scaled down
    // By defailt it looks for an image tag:
    opener: function(openerElement) {
      // openerElement is the element on which popup was initialized, in this case its <a> tag
      // you don't need to add "opener" option if this code matches your needs, it's defailt one.
      return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
    }
  }

}); </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to know how to add the class in right place or if there any modification i should add to make the script works ?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but don't use the mysql extension in PHP. It's been deprecated for a while and is officially removed in PHP 7. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Install Firebug in your Firefox and check out if there are some errors.

Comment: @SamHH I know about mysql problem but now am asking for how to add js and css code to retrive image ?

Comment: If you _know_ the problem lies in JS and CSS, will you update the question to only show the output of PHP instead of the PHP code?

Answer (score -1):

***EDITED:*** Please see revisions below... could this still be the issue?

```
<script src="jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

<script src="../jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

<script src="..js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried it but still not works , please check the syntax in echo line i think the problem in it

Comment: Just realised you were talking about the js file not css haha, my bad!

Comment: i tried them all but still no works , is my code true at echo statement ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "is my code true at echo statement"?

Comment: the script now works but when i click on a photo it give me the photo couldn't be loaded ?